# Combine validation errors and return one single message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two arrays I want to validate in my custom `Request`:

```
$rules = [
  'params.words1.*.value' => 'required|string|between:5,50',
  'params.words2.*.value' => 'required|string|between:5,50',
];
```

This returns an error message per each word. But I want a single general message like "Some of the words are invalid".
Is there any Laravel-way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$messages = [
    'params.*' => 'Some of the words are invalid.',
];
```

EDIT:

I think I may have found a solution:

First, make sure you import both Validator and HttpResponseException at the top:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
```

Then, you can override the native `failedValidation` method and alter your errors however you want:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
    // Get all the errors thrown
    $errors = collect($validator->errors());
    // Manipulate however you want. I'm just getting the first one here,
    // but you can use whatever logic fits your needs.
    $error  = $errors->unique()->first();

    // Either throw the exception, or return it any other way.
    throw new HttpResponseException(response(
        $error,
        422
    ));
}
```

Comment: I tried, but this only spams the same message multiple times.

(I added this to my `Request`:
`public function messages() {
        $messages = [
            'params.words2.*' => 'Some of the words are invalid.',
        ];
        return $messages;
    }`)

Comment: Check out my edit. I think I may have found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the bail parameter?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

This should only return the first validation error, and if all your rules havethe same validation error message, this would get the desired result.

EDIT: This is for Laravel 5.2 and up.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems not to work with array validation. It still validates each single item and returns a message per item.

Comment: @red1575 what's your laravel version? Seems like this is supported from 5.2 and up. If you have a version newer than that, then it should be working. If it's still not working, or you have an older version, perhaps try it with multiple validators? First validate `params.words1.*.value` then another validator to validate `params.words2.*.value` - this is just theorizing on my part but should work. Definitely not the prettiest solution though.

Comment: Also, it's probably going to return multiple messages even with the `bail` parameter, if you have multiple fields in input matching `params.words1.*.value`. If that's the case you will probably need to set more explicit field names.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use PHPs implode function to merge them into one single string. But make sure to use the all function `$validateRequest->errors()->all()`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#working-with-error-messages

example:

```php
implode(" ", $validateRequest->errors()->all())
```

This is an example for validating a card.

```php
// validate
        $validateRequest = Validator::make(array_merge(['patient_id' => $patient_id], $request->all()), [
            'patient_id' => 'required|integer',
            'card_number' => 'required|digits_between:15,16|unique:bg_card,card_number',
            'card_exp_month' => 'required|numeric|max:12|min:1|digits:2',
            'card_exp_year' => 'required|digits:4',
            'card_cvc' => 'nullable|string',
            'card_holder_name' => 'required|string',
            'address_line1' => 'nullable|string',
            'address_line2' => 'nullable|string',
            'address_city' => 'nullable|string',
            'address_state' => 'nullable|string',
            'address_zip' => 'nullable|string',
            'address_country' => 'nullable|string',
            'metadata' => 'nullable|json',
            'status' => 'nullable|string',
        ], [
            'card_number.unique' => 'The card number is already in use. or Has already been registered.',
        ]);

        if ($validateRequest->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => implode(" ", $validateRequest->errors()->all()),
                'errors' => $validateRequest->errors()->all(),
            ], 422);
        }
```